# Center two divs side by side in contact form

Tags: css

I'm trying to center two input fields side by side together with horizontally centering. I have two problems, the first one is that the two input fields for whatever reason overlap each other a little.

The closest I have been to solving this problem is to use "box-sizing: border-box" but that, unfortunately, removes the padding and thus change the design. The second problem is that I need both of the input fields to be in the center.

```css
.quote-page .contact .box {
  width: 70%;
}

.quote-page .contact .box .left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.quote-page .contact .box .right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.quote-page .form-2 {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left">
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-2">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the complete script so you can see the problem:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdQqeN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea but unfortunately you are going to have make additional adjustments to what you're creating whether you use the `box-sizing: border-box;` or not.

The reason it's acting funny is because without border-box you are going over the total of 100% width.

In order to create what you want, I've adjusted the following:

- Changed the width of the `.box`
- Added an `overflow: hidden;` to `.box` to prevent it from collapsing with the floated children
- Added `margin: 0 auto;` to center the children to `.box`
- Changed the width of `.box .left` to `width: 49%;` and a `margin-right: 1%;` (assuming you wanted space between the inputs)
- Same as the above item but for `.box .right`
- Added `box-sizing: border-box` to `.form-2`, and increased the height to 40px and padding to 12px

Here's an updated pen using border-box on just your middle inputs:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxpRVK

---

**CSS**

```
.quote-page .contact .box {
  width: 73.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.quote-page .contact .box .left {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.quote-page .contact .box .right {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.quote-page .form-2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

**HTML** (No Changes)

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="left">
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-2" placeholder="Enter your email" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="right">
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-2" placeholder="Enter your email" required="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot and thank you for a detailed explanation, now I understand why I had such a hard time with this.

Comment: You're very welcome. I do have additional suggestions but one overarching one I'd like to make is that you consider added * { box-sizing: border-box; }. It will force you to make some adjustments but you'll find it much, much easier to build your layout. @skribe

Answer (score 0):

Hardly visible, but they're in the middle and next to each other.

I added the div with class `.quote-page`. You were referring to it in your CSS but in the HTML it was missing. Here it is the top element set to a width of 100%.

The div.box element is centered via `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
.quote-page {
  width: 100%;
}

.quote-page .box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}

.quote-page .contact .box .left {
  width: 50%;
}

.quote-page .contact .box .right {
  width: 50%;
}

.quote-page .form-2 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-page">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="left">
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-2">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way...

Add css

```
.box {text-align: center;}
.left, .right {display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: At first here I added a wrapper, but on second look it was not necessary...